# Yii gives error in extension tinymce

Tags: php, yii

I've installed this extension: [TinyMCE](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-tinymce/)

My problem is that when I use the code given from that link this error shows:
Unknown variable form.

Here's the code:

```
use moonland\tinymce\TinyMCE;


echo TinyMCE::widget(['name' => 'text-content']);

$form->field($model, 'attribute')->widget(TinyMCE::className());

//toggle to tinyMCE or to textarea

echo TinyMCE::widget(['name' => 'text-content', 'toggle' => ['active' => true]]);

$form->field($model, 'attribute')->widget(TinyMCE::className(), [
    'toggle' => [
        'active' => true,
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just copying and pasting the code. The documentation does not always show the full code rather show technical code snippet performing the key role.
It is obvious from error that you have not defined form in your code.
here is the code to define form.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use moonland\tinymce\TinyMCE;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    echo TinyMCE::widget(['name' => 'text-content']);

$form->field($model, 'attribute')->widget(TinyMCE::className());

//toggle to tinyMCE or to textarea

echo TinyMCE::widget(['name' => 'text-content', 'toggle' => ['active' => true]]);

$form->field($model, 'attribute')->widget(TinyMCE::className(), [
    'toggle' => [
        'active' => true,
    ]
]);

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```